# Echoing a PHP array is only displaying the first letter of each value

Tags: php, arrays

This is a simple rating system. There are 3 values which contain a percentage with an accompanying description/name. I only want to display the the description/name.

For some reason, it displays:

A

T

I

This is my script:

```
if(isset($_POST['analyze'])) {

    // get total value of "Time Management" section
    for($i = 0; $i < 19; $i++) {
        $time_management_total += $_POST["time_management_Q$i"];
    }


    // get total value of "Attract Clients" section
    for($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) {
        $attract_clients_total += $_POST["attract_clients_Q$i"];
    }

    // get total value of "Internet Marketing" section
    for($i = 0; $i < 21; $i++) {
        $internet_marketing_total += $_POST["internet_marketing_Q$i"];
    }


    // calculate user's personal "Time Management" score
    $time_management_rating = ($time_management_total / 19) / 5;

    // calculate user's personal "Attract Clients" score
    $attract_clients_rating = ($attract_clients_total / 16) / 5;

    // calculate user's personal "Internet Marketing" score
    $internet_marketing_rating = ($internet_marketing_total / 21) / 5;


    // add user ratings to array
    $user_rating[0] = array('percent' => $time_management_rating, 'description' => 'Time Management');
    $user_rating[1] = array('percent' => $attract_clients_rating, 'description' => 'Attract Clients');
    $user_rating[2] = array('percent' => $internet_marketing_rating, 'description' => 'Internet Marketing');


    // reverse sort the array - highest percentage first
    rsort($user_rating);


    // echo the description
    foreach($user_rating as $category) {
        foreach($category as $description) {
            echo $description[description] . "<br />";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you're only getting the first letter because you're referencing the strings char array.  so index 0 would be the first letter of the string :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do:

```
foreach($user_rating as $category) {
        echo $category['description'] . "<br />";
}
```

---

Explanation of your code:

Your array is like

```
$user_rating = array(array('percent' => ..., 'description' => ...), array(...));
```

That means you have a two-dimensional array.

When you do `foreach($user_rating as $category)`, you are looping over the outer array. That means `$category` will be an array, namely, `array('percent' => ..., 'description' => ...)`.

Now you make the mistake, to loop over that array again, which means that `$description` will always be the string value of `percent` and `description`.

In PHP you can access strings with array notation to get the character at that position. As `description` is not defined it probably resolves to `0` and you get the first character.

```
$foo = 'bar';
echo $foo[0];
// echos 'b'
```

By just adding some `echo`s, you can see, which element in your loop contains which value:

```
$user_rating[0] = array('description' => 'Time Management');
$user_rating[1] = array('description' => 'Attract Clients');
$user_rating[2] = array('description' => 'Internet Marketing');

foreach($user_rating as $category) {
    echo '$category: ' . $category . PHP_EOL;
    foreach($category as $description) {
        echo '$description: '. $description . PHP_EOL;
        echo $description[description] . "<br />" .PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

gives

```
$category: Array
$description: Time Management
T<br />
$category: Array
$description: Attract Clients
A<br />
$category: Array
$description: Internet Marketing
I<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
echo $description[description]
```

to

```
echo $description['description']
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
foreach($user_rating as $category) {
            echo $category['description'] . "<br />";
    }
```